# Move child element with mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to know if there's a way to explore the content of a div by moving mouse? like for example having a **1000px*1000px** pic inside a **500px*500px** div content in `overflow:hidden` and being able to see the rest of the picture by putting the cursor in the right-bottom side of the div.

And if there's a way how should I proceed ?

Comment: A request for code like this is not actually a question, and is not suitable for Stack Overflow. I recommend you take a look at this - **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)** - and head back when you have a specific programming-related question.

Comment: Describe better how the image should behave. Should it scroll or something?

Comment: Ah, I'm not asking for a code, just the way I should proceed, like should I use a grid above the div going at different speed up/down right/left but if I do it sounds to me like I'd need to do a lot of grid just to do so so maybe there's another "way". I surely dont want people to do the work for me, just to give me a hint. I want to learn not to get carried, sorry if the way I asked my question led to this misunderstanding I just have no idea of how to ask it as I dont really know what it is I want to ask (i.e. is it really "exploring" a div, I dont really know if it's the right therm)

Comment: @dfsq yes it should, the same way a smartphone goes arround a website.

Comment: Explain how exactly you want to "explore the rest of the picture". There can be multiple ways. It's not clear what you need.

Comment: @dfsq it's like scrolling depending on where my cursor is. for example if my cursor is at the bottom it will scroll down automaticly. it's like a carousel except that it should not act vertically or horizontally only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something nice and smooth?

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  const $mmGal = $('#mmGal'),
    $mmImg = $('#mmImg'),
    damp = 10; // 1 = immediate, higher number = smoother response

  let X = 0, Y = 0,
    mX = 0, mY = 0,
    wDiff = 0, hDiff = 0,
    zeno, tOut;

  // Get image size after it's loaded
  $mmImg.one('load', function() {
    wDiff = (this.width / $mmGal.width()) - 1;
    hDiff = (this.height / $mmGal.height()) - 1;
  }).each(function() {
    if (this.complete) $(this).trigger("load");
  });

  $mmGal.on({
    mousemove(ev) {
      mX = ev.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      mY = ev.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    },
    mouseenter() {
      clearTimeout(tOut);
      clearInterval(zeno);
      zeno = setInterval(function() { // Zeno's paradox "catching delay"
        X += (mX - X) / damp;
        Y += (mY - Y) / damp;
        // Use CSS transition
        $mmImg.css({transform: `translate(${-X * wDiff}px, ${-Y * hDiff}px)`});
        // If instead you want to use scroll:
        // $mmGal[0].scrollTo(X * wDiff, Y * hDiff);
      }, 26);
    },
    mouseleave() {
      // Allow the image to move for some time even after mouseleave
      tOut = setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(zeno);
      }, 1200);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#mmGal {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
}

#mmImg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mmGal">
  <img id="mmImg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfcTY.jpg">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

- Here's another similar approach to [mousemove element in opposite direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72827867/383904)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes

Comment: wow that's exactly what I was looking for, very impressive and clear to understand, thanks awfully !

Answer (score 0):

give widht and height to div wrapped for the image

here is the [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jcyrd)

on `:hover` add `overflow: visible;` to the div

Answer (score 0):

This is almost what you want. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/RM9wK/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"><img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3668/12858161173_8daa0b7e54_b.jpg"/></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container img {
    position: relative;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#container" ).mousemove(function( event ) {

      var width = $("#container img").width();
      var height = $("#container img").height();
      var divWidth = $("#container").width();
      var divHeight = $("#container").height();

      var xPos = (width / divWidth - 1) * event.pageX
      var yPos = (height / divHeight -1) * event.pageY

      $("#container img").css('left', '-'+ xPos+'px');
      $("#container img").css('top', '-'+ yPos+'px');

    });
});
```

Comment: on every single mousemove - to force jQuery to lookup the document again for the same selectors is a really bad idea

Comment: Thats exactly what the questioner wanted

Comment: The dom lookup is not really needed if he can hard code the width and height

Comment: Don't mix `sizes` with `selectors` please. Read again my comment.

Answer (score -1):

I would use "triggers" (hot spot) ~ add some small div element and set their position as you want, now when mouse enter trigger some events....

Simple Example: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shlomohassid/4HxZ7/)

**CSS**

```
div.container {
    position:relative;
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
.trigger {
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:transparent; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
    <img src='http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/12f0cc69cd9742faa9c8ee0f7b0d210e.jpg' />
    <div class='trigger'></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.trigger').mouseenter(
  function(){
    $(this).parent('.container').css({
        'width':'220px',
        'height':'250px'
    });
  });
$('.container').mouseleave(
  function(){
    $(this).css({
        'width':'100px',
        'height':'100px'
    });
});
```

Comment: the question is how to explore all the rest of the image while **moving** your mouse over the containing area, logically if you reach with the mouse the bottom right corner you diagonally explored most of the image. Also in jQuery there's no need to set `: '220px'` just `: 200`. jQuery is incredibly smart in this things. Also concerning a better UI and UX, one should avoid to flash content all around the page.