# Move div on mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to adopt a script I have found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125365/explore-div-content-by-moving-mouse), but changing the image to some content seems to be harder than I thought.

The script is quite simple and should make the `#content` div move inside the `holder` on `mousemove`:

```
// written by Roko C. Buljan

var $mmGal = $('#holder'),
      $mmImg = $('#content'),
      damp = 10, // higher number = smoother response
      X = 0, Y = 0,
      mX = 0, mY = 0,
      wDiff, hDiff,
      zeno;

  function motion(){
    zeno = setInterval(function(){ // Zeno's paradox "catching delay"
      X += (mX-X) / damp; 
      Y += (mY-Y) / damp;        
      $mmGal.scrollLeft(X*wDiff).scrollTop(Y*hDiff);
    }, 26);
  }

  // Get image size after it's loaded and run our fn  
  $mmImg.one('load', function() {   
    wDiff = ( this.width/$mmGal.width() )-1,          
    hDiff = (this.height/$mmGal.height())-1; 
  }).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
  });


  $mmGal.mousemove(function(e) {
    mX = e.pageX-this.offsetLeft;
    mY = e.pageY-this.offsetTop;  
  }).hover(function( e ){
    return e.type=='mouseenter'? motion() : setTimeout(function(){
      clearInterval(zeno);
    },1200); // clear if not used
  });
```

Why doesn't the div `#content` move (text and image)?

[**Example JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/sugilopala/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Do you want the content to move or only image ?

Comment: I want to move the whole div `#content`, so the text and image :)

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the demo and added content on **moving background** image.

**Check the demo:**

```js
$(function(){
  
  var $mmGal = $('#mmGal'),
      $mmImg = $('#mmImg'),
      damp = 10, // higher number = smoother response
      X = 0, Y = 0,
      mX = 0, mY = 0,
      wDiff, hDiff,
      zeno;
 
  function motion(){
    zeno = setInterval(function(){ // Zeno's paradox "catching delay"
      X += (mX-X) / damp; 
      Y += (mY-Y) / damp;        
      $mmGal.scrollLeft(X*wDiff).scrollTop(Y*hDiff);
    }, 26);
  }
  
  // Get image size after it's loaded and run our fn  
  $mmImg.one('load', function() {   
    wDiff = ( this.width/$mmGal.width() )-1,          
    hDiff = (this.height/$mmGal.height())-1; 
  }).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
  });
  
   
  $mmGal.mousemove(function(e) {
    mX = e.pageX-this.offsetLeft;
    mY = e.pageY-this.offsetTop;  
  }).hover(function( e ){
    return e.type=='mouseenter'? motion() : setTimeout(function(){
      clearInterval(zeno);
    },1200); // clear if not used
  });

});
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
.main-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
#mmGal{
    position:relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width:412px;
    height:220px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#eee;
    z-index: 0;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. quae molestias ad dolores qui blanditiis,   Quas eaque soluta quia ipsa?  aliquam?</p>
</div>
<div id="mmGal">
   <img id="mmImg" src="http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/rawfile/2013/11/offset_WaterHouseMarineImages_62652-2-660x440.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My [original script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22126357/383904) uses a `.load()` for the *underlay* image to load. Since you don't have a background image to move - you don't need necessarily that code part.
Calculate `w/hDiff` inside the `mousemove` event.
Also, use jQuery's `.outerWidth()` and `.innerWidth()` for the calculation:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  const $mm = $('#holder'),
        $mmCont = $('#content'),
        damp = 10; // 1 = immediate, higher number = smoother response

  let X = 0, Y = 0,
      mX = 0, mY = 0,
      wDiff = 0, hDiff = 0,
      zeno, tOut;

  $mm.on({
    mousemove(ev) {
      wDiff = ($mmCont.innerWidth() / $mm.outerWidth()) -1,          
      hDiff = ($mmCont.innerHeight() / $mm.outerHeight()) -1; 
      mX = ev.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      mY = ev.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    },
    mouseenter() {
      clearTimeout(tOut);
      clearInterval(zeno);
      zeno = setInterval(function() { // Zeno's paradox "catching delay"
        X += (mX - X) / damp;
        Y += (mY - Y) / damp;
        // Use CSS transition:
        // $mmCont.css({ transform: `translate(${-X * wDiff}px, ${-Y * hDiff}px)` });
        // Use Scroll:
        $mm[0].scrollTo(X * wDiff, Y * hDiff);
      }, 26);
    },
    mouseleave() {
      // Allow the image to move for some time even after mouseleave
      tOut = setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(zeno);
      }, 1200);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#holder {
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 180px;
}

#content {
  width: 150%;
  height: 600px;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <div id="content">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus dolore impedit dignissimos porro repellendus numquam aut quibusdam, consequuntur modi facere? Totam ut libero corporis sit sequi explicabo ab magni quaerat unde animi aliquid facere
      necessitatibus, quae molestias ad dolores qui blanditiis, quisquam minima beatae autem iure. Neque animi tempore iste accusamus ut cum ipsam possimus, perspiciatis quia illo obcaecati sed molestiae amet architecto, nostrum cumque quaerat minima
      minus, consequatur rem error nihil. Ipsa eveniet, praesentium suscipit optio blanditiis at, vel illum harum omnis quam. Quas eaque soluta quia ipsa? Illum inventore veritatis facilis eveniet voluptatibus atque laborum necessitatibus adipisci aliquam?</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfcTY.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```