# Move element on mousemove in opposite direction

Tags: javascript, html, css

The `while` statement in `"onmousemove"` event doesn't seem to work

I'm trying to make a horizontal scrolling page that gets scrolled with mouse position. I managed to make it work using

```js
<script>
        const width = window.innerWidth;
        const height = window.innerHeight;
        const windowCenterX = width / 2;
        const windowCenterY = height / 2;
        document.onmousemove = function(e){
            var x = e.clientX; 
            var y = e.clientY;
            const transformedX = x - windowCenterX;
            document.getElementById("mouse-value").innerHTML = transformedX;
            document.getElementById("mouse-circle").style.top = y - 15 + "px";
            document.getElementById("mouse-circle").style.left = document.documentElement.scrollLeft + x - 20 + "px";
            if (transformedX > 0) {
              document.documentElement.scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft + 0.01*x;
            }
            if (transformedX < 0) {
              document.documentElement.scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft - 0.01*x;
            }
        }
</script>
```

but the problem with that is: if my mouse isn't moving, it doesn't move the screen either.
So I thought: why not put a

```js
while (transformedX > 0) {
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft + 0.01 * x;
}
```

now for some reason, this breaks everything and I don't know why.
Is there a better way to  always update page's `scrollLeft` on mouse position?
here's the whole code :

```js
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;
const windowCenterX = width / 2;
const windowCenterY = height / 2;
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  const transformedX = x - windowCenterX;
  document.getElementById("mouse-value").innerHTML = transformedX;
  document.getElementById("mouse-circle").style.top = y - 15 + "px";
  document.getElementById("mouse-circle").style.left = document.documentElement.scrollLeft + x - 20 + "px";
  if (transformedX > 0) {
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft + 0.01 * x;
  }
  if (transformedX < 0) {
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft - 0.01 * x;
  }
  while (transformedX > 0) {
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft + 0.01 * x;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100% !important;
}

#main-content {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 9000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, #000);
}

#mouse-circle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {}

#right-arrow {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 90%;
  top: 45%;
}

#mouse-position {
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="mouse-circle"></div>

<div id="main-content">
  <div id="right-arrow">
    <i style="color: white; margin: 35%;font-size: 25px;" class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div id="mouse-position">
    <p id="mouse-value">0</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: *"a horizontal scrolling page that gets scrolled with mouse movement"* and then *"if my mouse isn't moving, it doesn't move the screen either"*. Isn't that the purpose of your task?

Comment: `transformedX` doesn't change inside the loop. It's either false, or always true. You have a conditional endless loop.

Comment: @Cid yeah corrected the sentence, I guess mouse position makes more sence

Comment: @deceze I added : var x = e.clientX; vartransformedX = x - windowCenterX; inside the loop but it still doesn't work

Comment: then you rather need to define a zone for scroll left and another one for scroll right, then use the event `mousehover` to check when the mouse is inside the zones

Comment: Yes, because the way you're doing it currently there's no way to stop the scrolling other than waiting for the scroll position to be at their min/max.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan well if update the mouse position in the while, the way to stop it would be to put the mouse position back to center but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: You mean you want something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22126357/383904

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan no, that i have managed to do already. If you stop moving your mouse the image stop moving even if it's at the far right/left which means that you can't get to the end of the content, something like that "https://square.geex-arts.com/"

Comment: @hey That's not true.  [The UI](https://square.geex-arts.com/) has a no-move sweetspot in an area in the center of the screen. The "background" moves faster if your mouse reaches the edges of the screen in that direction. The "background" stops moving just because there's no more background to show, not because your mouse is still (mouse stops moving).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollTo/Left/Top` cannot handle decimal values.

I would do it in a different way:

- On `"pointermove"` just call a function that calculates the speed for X and Y directions. Those values are two float values from 0.0 to 1.0.
- Inside a looping `requestAnimationFrame` - move the Area.

The *speed* for X and Y are only calculated in a specific padding region inside the *Viewport* element, in order to allow to the pointer to rest in the middle of the *Viewport* without moving the *Area*. Such is determined by a variable `padd` (from 0.0 to 0.5)

In order to make every *Area* child element reachable with the pointer without the Area moving — the area needs to be able to move maximally till one of the edges touches the viewport center.

Move the *Area* by an offset relative to its center using CSS `transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate3d(offsetX, offsetY, 0);`

Proof of concept:

```js
const elView = document.querySelector("#view");
const elArea = document.querySelector("#area");
const padd = 0.4; // Reactive padding pointer area (0.0 min to 0.5 max) 
const maxMove = 5; // px
const speed = {x: 0, y: 0};
const offset = {x: 0, y: 0};

const updatePos = (evt) => {
  const bcrView = elView.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, (evt.clientX - bcrView.left) / bcrView.width));
  const y = Math.min(1, Math.max(0, (evt.clientY - bcrView.top) / bcrView.height));
  speed.x = 0;
  speed.y = 0;
  if (x < padd) {
    speed.x = (x / padd) - 1;
  } else if (x > (1 - padd)) {
    speed.x = (x - (1 - padd)) / padd;
  }
  if (y < padd) {
    speed.y = (y / padd) - 1;
  } else if (y > (1 - padd)) {
    speed.y = (y - (1 - padd)) / padd;
  }
};

const moveArea = () => {
  const bcrArea = elArea.getBoundingClientRect();
  const w2 = bcrArea.width / 2;
  const h2 = bcrArea.height / 2;
  offset.x -= speed.x * maxMove;
  offset.y -= speed.y * maxMove;
  offset.x = Math.max(-w2, Math.min(w2, offset.x));
  offset.y = Math.max(-h2, Math.min(h2, offset.y));
  elArea.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) translate3d(${offset.x}px, ${offset.y}px, 0)`;
  requestAnimationFrame(moveArea);
};

requestAnimationFrame(moveArea);

elView.addEventListener("pointermove", updatePos);
elView.addEventListener("pointerleave", () => {
  speed.x = 0;
  speed.y = 0;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#view {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  touch-action: none;
}

#area {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(50px * 20);
  height: calc(50px * 16);
  background-color: #e5e5f7;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#444cf7 2px, transparent 2px), linear-gradient(90deg, #444cf7 2px, transparent 2px), linear-gradient(#444cf7 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(90deg, #444cf7 1px, #e5e5f7 1px);
  background-size: 50px 50px, 50px 50px, 10px 10px, 10px 10px;
  background-position: -2px -2px, -2px -2px, -1px -1px, -1px -1px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
}

.centerDot {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="view">
  <div id="area">
    <div class="centerDot"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="centerDot"></div>
</div>
```